# I want to find the sum of the results of count

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, sum

I use mysql to find the count of production I have done per day, I modified the code such that I can find the time the data has been submitted. But the results show each data submitted at each minute or second. That is when i ask for count between 7 to 4 pm, what I wish for is a simple answer like 300 or 400. but what i get is : at 07:01 = 1,  at 07:17 = 1, like this. So simple need is that i want the sum of all these . that is i want the sum of count from one time to another. Following is the code:

```
SELECT
a.id as batch_id,
a.name as batch_name,
a.template_id as template,
c.user as reviewer,
date(b.created_at) as judgment_date,
time(b.updated_at) as judgement_time,
count(distinct c.task_id) total_keywords_judged,
count(distinct c.item_id) total_items_judged
FROM judgment_samples a
JOIN user_task_judgments b ON a.id = b.sample_id and b.user != 'sdat_cache'
JOIN user_task_item_judgments c on b.task_id = c.task_id and c.user != 'sdat_cache' and b.user = c.user
WHERE
date(b.created_at) between '2021-03-12' and '2021-03-12'
AND
time(b.updated_at)  between '12:00:00' and '14:37:00'
AND c.user NOT LIKE 'Appen%'
AND a.teams like ('%internal%') 
GROUP BY a.template_id,a.id, a.name, c.user, judgment_date , judgement_time, judgments
ORDER BY a.template_id,a.id
```

Comment: what you will get if you remove last two lines, i.e group by?

Comment: @GokulnathP You would get a malformed query with unpredictable results -- that MySQL will unfortunately run.

Answer (score 0):

I thnk main culprit here is your GROUP BY clause. You may try with below updated query -

```
SELECT a.id as batch_id,
       a.name as batch_name,
       a.template_id as template,
       c.user as reviewer,
       date(b.created_at) as judgment_date,
       time(b.updated_at) as judgement_time,
       count(distinct c.task_id) total_keywords_judged,
       count(distinct c.item_id) total_items_judged
FROM judgment_samples a
JOIN user_task_judgments b ON a.id = b.sample_id and b.user != 'sdat_cache'
JOIN user_task_item_judgments c on b.task_id = c.task_id and c.user != 'sdat_cache' and b.user = c.user
WHERE date(b.created_at) between '2021-03-12' and '2021-03-12'
AND time(b.updated_at)  between '12:00:00' and '14:37:00'
AND c.user NOT LIKE 'Appen%'
AND a.teams like ('%internal%') 
GROUP BY a.id, a.name, a.template_id, c.user, date(b.created_at) , time(b.updated_at)
ORDER BY a.template_id,a.id
```